# FORM_DIRECTIVES

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

[here](http://blog.ng-book.com/category/ng2/) we can read that we need `FORM_DIRECTIVES` to work with `ngForm` or `ngSubmit` but for me it is working the same without the `FORM_DIRECTIVES` include.

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Because  FORM_DIRECTIVES is included by default, just like CORE_DIRECTIVES.

Comment: So there is no need to import `FORM_DIRECTIVES` and add it to `directives`?

Comment: No it's for custom directives and components (not included in the core)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular2 final

```ts
@NgModule({
  // only one of these is requured if only one is used
  imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  ...
 })
```

is required. `FORM_DIRECTIVES` don't exist anymore.